# How to set response hours for a Dialogflow ES agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to set response hours for a Dialogflow ES agent to make it responses only for a specific period of time each day. For weekday, from 22:00 to 09:00 of the next following day. For weekend, from 20:00 to 11:00 of the next following day.

My idea is to stop all integrations from chat platforms automatically, however I can't find any API to do it, In [Manage agents with the API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/agent-create-api), there are only APIs to create and delete agents.

Please give me any suggestion to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the time in Webhook fulfillment. If it's not your business hours, you can replace it with a guide message about your chatbot's hours.